# Rocky Linux 8.6: conflicting packages when upgrading?

Tags: linux, apache-http-server, redhat-enterprise-linux

After deploying a Rocky Linux VM which is intended to run as a web server I did an update and got these messages:

```
[root@rocky ~]# dnf upgrade --refresh -y
Rocky Linux 8 - AppStream                                                                                                                              12 kB/s | 4.8 kB     00:00    
Rocky Linux 8 - BaseOS                                                                                                                                 16 kB/s | 4.3 kB     00:00    
Rocky Linux 8 - Extras                                                                                                                                 12 kB/s | 3.5 kB     00:00    
Rocky Linux 8 - PowerTools                                                                                                                             17 kB/s | 4.8 kB     00:00    
Extra Packages for Enterprise Linux 7 - x86_64                                                                                                         51 kB/s |  31 kB     00:00    
Extra Packages for Enterprise Linux 7 - x86_64                                                                                                        4.8 MB/s |  17 MB     00:03    
Safe Remi's RPM repository for Enterprise Linux 7 - x86_64                                                                                             22 kB/s | 3.0 kB     00:00    
Safe Remi's RPM repository for Enterprise Linux 7 - x86_64                                                                                            3.9 MB/s | 2.8 MB     00:00    
Error: 
 Problem 1: cannot install the best update candidate for package libidn2-2.2.0-1.el8.x86_64
  - nothing provides libunistring.so.0()(64bit) needed by libidn2-2.3.2-1.el7.x86_64
 Problem 2: package remi-release-7.9-3.el7.remi.noarch requires epel-release = 7, but none of the providers can be installed
  - cannot install both epel-release-8-13.el8.noarch and epel-release-7-14.noarch
  - cannot install both epel-release-7-14.noarch and epel-release-8-13.el8.noarch
  - cannot install the best update candidate for package remi-release-7.9-3.el7.remi.noarch
  - cannot install the best update candidate for package epel-release-7-14.noarch
(try to add '--allowerasing' to command line to replace conflicting packages or '--skip-broken' to skip uninstallable packages or '--nobest' to use not only best candidate packages)
[root@rocky ~]#
```

I have installed Apache 2.4, PHP 7.4. and remi PHP 8, MariaDB which all installed successfully and run flawlessly.
But I noticed that they don't have the latest versions: Apache is 2.4.37 instead of 2.4.53, PHP is 7.4.19 instead of 7.4.29.
So I decided to upgrade using `dnf upgrade --refresh -y`, but I stumbled upon the above messages.

What is going wrong here ?

Answer (score 0):

> Rocky Linux 8 - PowerTools                                                                                                                             17 kB/s | 4.8 kB     00:00
> Extra Packages for Enterprise Linux 7 - x86_64                                                                                                         51 kB/s |  31 kB     00:00

You are trying to use **EL-7** repositories on Rocky 8, this of course cannot work

You have to use the **EL-8** EPEL and Remi repositories

Remove the **epel-release** and **remi-release** package and follow the [wizard instructions](https://rpms.remirepo.net/wizard/) for a proper configuration.

Comment: Thanks !
That worked !